# Pandas building a histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

`Price  Postcode Type                Town
Date

2003-05-16  397500  BS22 7YA    D   WESTON-SUPER-MARE
2003-09-10  235000   PE9 3AE    D            STAMFORD
2003-11-28  150000  WA16 7RH    F           KNUTSFORD
2003-03-05   95000  PL13 1AT    T                LOOE
2003-09-19  112950   CF5 1HF    T             CARDIFF
2003-08-27  155000   CM0 7LY    D        SOUTHMINSTER
2003-11-17  147000   WD5 0BF    F      ABBOTS LANGLEY
2003-06-26  198000   CT6 6EE    D           HERNE BAY
2003-10-01  346000   LE2 2PD    D           LEICESTER
2003-10-13  163000  TD15 1QY    T  BERWICK-UPON-TWEED
2003-11-07  197000   W14 8HU    F              LONDON
2003-12-12  120000   SE7 7AB    F              LONDON
2003-03-10  110000  SY20 9LB    D         MACHYNLLETH
2003-08-22   46000  LL24 0RD    T        BETWS-Y-COED
2003-10-14   80000   CH7 6BQ    T                MOLD`

I have a csv file like above and need to display a histogram of frequency of transactions according to price brackets. How can I achieve this using pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Using pd.cut, get the price brackets

```
df['G']=pd.cut(df.Price,10)

df1=df.G.value_counts()
df1
Out[123]: 
(116300.0, 151450.0]    3
(81150.0, 116300.0]     3
(186600.0, 221750.0]    2
(151450.0, 186600.0]    2
(45648.5, 81150.0]      2
(362350.0, 397500.0]    1
(327200.0, 362350.0]    1
(221750.0, 256900.0]    1
(292050.0, 327200.0]    0
(256900.0, 292050.0]    0
Name: G, dtype: int64
df1.plot(kind='bar')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by frequency of transactions? My first guess would be number of transactions per unit time, but then you have one value per price bracket, and a simple bar or line graph is more appropriate than a histogram.

If that's all you want, then
 (1) create a new row with your price brackets,
 (2) [groupby()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#splitting-an-object-into-groups) that row, then [aggregate()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#aggregation) with a custom function that calculates the frequency
 (3) Use [Series.plot()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.plot.html) to generate the final plot.